# Display Salesforce page/component from Org1 in another salesforce Org2

Tags: visualforce, lightning, integration, canvas

I have a requirement to show VF/lighting page of salesforce Org1 in another Salesforce Org2.  However possible way just want to show the page/component in another salesforce org. Please let us know if this is feasible and suggest any approach ?

Thanks,

VK

Comment: Look into [Canvas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm)

Answer (score 0):

[Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm) could be appropriate solution for your situation. It allows to run Aura component apps outside of Salesforce servers. But it would require additional adjustments to get all work.